# Stacked heatmaps - seaborn solution?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

EDIT: For some reason I've been downvoted twice for posting this question (it hurts ppl) so I've rejigged it.

How do you combine multiple heatmaps in a stacked way with same  color scale like to following image?
Additionally, does anyone know how to create the Augmented suffix tree?

Background:

I've worked through the python jupyter notebooks at the following link on how to create the heatmaps of (any) daily consumption profiles using seaborn
http://www.datadrivenbuilding.org/
...however there's a realllllllly cool combination graphic I'd love to be able to reproduce.

[image: Get a better browser fool!]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've worked through the notebook to learn how to do individual heatmaps and then researched how to stack them but without progress. I didn't know where to start on the tree diagram as I didn't know what it was called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That image is an edited version of an image from this paper:

> C. Miller, Z. Nagy, A. Schlueter, Automated daily pattern filtering of
>   measured building performance data, Automation in Construction 49,
>   Part A (2015) 1–17. doi:10.1016/j.autcon.2014.09.004. URL
>   http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0926580514002015

They came up with the visualisation techniques themselves and describe them there. It looks like C. Miller is the one who wrote [the notebook that you already found that shows how to draw the stacked heatmaps](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/cmiller8/DayFilter/blob/master/DayFilter%20Process%20-%20Part%201%20-%20SAX.ipynb).

The augmented suffix tree is a type of visualization called a Sankey Diagram. You can plot these very beautifully using [Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/sankey-diagram/) for example, or [pySankey](https://github.com/anazalea/pySankey) if you want to use matplotlib.

Comment: Thank you. Though the notebook does not show how to do the stacked heatmaps, just individual ones.

Comment: Miller runs something like `In [46]` in the notebook for each group represented by an endpoint on the right hand side of the Sankey diagram, and aligns that output with the right hand side of the Sankey diagram.